# How can I write a JSON stream to file using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, leap-motion

I want to write a full JSON object to a file as it comes in. I'm currently using

```
const file = fs.createWriteStream('./example.file');
var inputStream = JSON.parse(generatedData);
fs.write(inputStream+"\n");
```

The stream I'm trying to capture comes from a [Leap Motion controller  *frame.dump*](https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap.Frame.html#Frame.dump). 
I've attempted to write the object using both *JSON.parse()* and *JSON.stringify()*, but it only seems to write ***undefined*** lines.

I'm probably not handling the object correctly, but I don't know how to resolve it.

EDIT: For clarification, I know how to write single elements of the JSON object, but I would prefer to dump the entire JSON to each new line.

Comment: What format is `generatedData` in above?

Comment: @Chev, that would be a JSON-formatted string, according to [the documentation](https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap.Frame.html#Frame.dump), but I can't say I have checked it, as I'm not sure how to investigate objects in Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`generatedData` is already a JSON string here and you are now parsing it back to an object which is not needed.

As you want to append to the file, I would consider [appendFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback)

```
fs.open('./example.txt', 'a', (err, fd) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.appendFile(fd, generatedData, 'utf8', (err) => {
    fs.close(fd, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the advantage of using _appendFile_ over _createWriteStream_ with a new line?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `createWriteStream` and would be more suitable if you logging more data continuously and need to keep the handle open to keep processing content. If you simply removed the `JSON.parse` in your example it would be fine. `appendFile` is convenient to open, write and close the handler to free up resources. But you can do the same with `createWriteStream`.